# How to create a columns with differences between last and first values within a groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a data like below:

```
{'grp': {0: 828893, 1: 828893, 2: 828893, 3: 828893, 4: 828893, 5: 828893, 6: 828893, 7: 828893, 8: 828893, 9: 828893, 10: 828893, 11: 828893, 12: 828893, 13: 828893, 14: 828893, 15: 828893, 16: 828893, 17: 828893, 18: 828893, 19: 828893, 20: 828893, 21: 828893, 22: 828893, 23: 828893, 24: 828893}, 'grp2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: '1', 5: '1', 6: '1', 7: '1', 8: '1', 9: '1', 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: '2', 13: '2', 14: '2', 15: '2', 16: nan, 17: nan, 18: nan, 19: '3', 20: nan, 21: '4', 22: '4', 23: '4', 24: '4'}, 'val1': {0: -50.0, 1: -50.0, 2: -50.0, 3: -50.0, 4: 7.600000000000001, 5: 54.599999999999994, 6: 38.599999999999994, 7: 50.599999999999994, 8: 91.0, 9: 100.80000000000001, 10: 19.200000000000003, 11: -50.0, 12: -50.0, 13: 69.6, 14: 42.0, 15: 90.19999999999999, 16: -50.0, 17: -50.0, 18: 47.599999999999994, 19: 98.80000000000001, 20: 27.599999999999994, 21: 11.799999999999997, 22: nan, 23: 13.0, 24: 0.0}, 'val2': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 30.1, 5: 21.5, 6: 20.7, 7: 4.2, 8: 5.0, 9: 21.6, 10: 85.1, 11: 0.0, 12: 0.0, 13: 36.4, 14: 56.6, 15: 51.2, 16: 0.0, 17: 0.0, 18: 58.5, 19: 42.2, 20: 76.1, 21: 68.7, 22: nan, 23: 90.3, 24: 95.3}}
```

I want to group it by columns `grp` and `grp2` first and then create a new columns `val1_b` and `val2_b` defined as a difference between last and first observation (within a group) from `val1` and `val2` respectively. A code in R would be something like:

```
ex %>% 
  group_by(grp, grp2) %>% 
  mutate(val1_b = last(val1) - first(val1),
         val2_b = last(val2) - first(val2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But I need to do it in Python. The nearest I can get is:

```
pd.DataFrame(ex).groupby(['grp', 'grp2'])['val1'].apply(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])
```

but this is only for one column and results are summarised instead of added to excisting data frame. Therefore, how can I calculate differences between last and first observation within a group for several columns and add it as new columns to excisting data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and 
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), one possible solution with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for new columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ex)
#columns for processing defined after groupby
g = df.groupby(['grp', 'grp2'])['val1', 'val2']
out = df.join((g.transform('last') - g.transform('first')).add_prefix('new_'))
```

Like @Wen-Ben mentioned in comments is possible alternative with no `join` (thank you):

```
df[['new_val1',  'new_val2']] = g.transform('last') - g.transform('first')
```

---

```
print (out)
       grp grp2   val1  val2  new_val1  new_val2
0   828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
1   828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
2   828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
3   828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
4   828893    1    7.6  30.1      93.2      -8.5
5   828893    1   54.6  21.5      93.2      -8.5
6   828893    1   38.6  20.7      93.2      -8.5
7   828893    1   50.6   4.2      93.2      -8.5
8   828893    1   91.0   5.0      93.2      -8.5
9   828893    1  100.8  21.6      93.2      -8.5
10  828893  NaN   19.2  85.1       NaN       NaN
11  828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
12  828893    2  -50.0   0.0     140.2      51.2
13  828893    2   69.6  36.4     140.2      51.2
14  828893    2   42.0  56.6     140.2      51.2
15  828893    2   90.2  51.2     140.2      51.2
16  828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
17  828893  NaN  -50.0   0.0       NaN       NaN
18  828893  NaN   47.6  58.5       NaN       NaN
19  828893    3   98.8  42.2       0.0       0.0
20  828893  NaN   27.6  76.1       NaN       NaN
21  828893    4   11.8  68.7     -11.8      26.6
22  828893    4    NaN   NaN     -11.8      26.6
23  828893    4   13.0  90.3     -11.8      26.6
24  828893    4    0.0  95.3     -11.8      26.6
```

Comment: That does calculations, but it's still contracted version of data frame - how can I add it to original data frame? One option would be `join` probably, but maybe there is more efficient solution?

Comment: Right now it is look much better

Comment: @jakes - Edited answer with some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `mutate` in R  , here in `pandas` is `transform`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(ex)
g=df.groupby(['grp', 'grp2'])
df['val1_b']=g['val1'].transform('first')-g['val1'].transform('last')
df['val2_b']=g['val2'].transform('first')-g['val1'].transform('last')
```